# Running Checker Framework on Android

Tags: android, gradle, checker-framework

I want to use Checker Framework to do some static analysis of my app-  checking for Nullability failures, UI constraint failures, etc at runtime.  I followed the instructions at https://checkerframework.org/manual/#android-gradle  to try and make it run, but I'm getting an error that checkTypes is not a task.  I think I followed the instructions correctly, and I fixed the capitalization mismatch they had.  ANy ideas how to fix it?  My build.gradle is below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    google()
}

apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'

gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xmaxerrs" << "500"
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.handshake.hsdm"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 35
        versionName "0.0.35"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            testCoverageEnabled = false
        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled = false
        }
        checkTypes {
            javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.
                    classNames.add("org.checkerframework.checker.guieffect.GuiEffectChecker")
            // You can pass options like so:
            // javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.arguments.put("warns", "")
        }

    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        //These files constantly step on each other from multiple libraries, don't include them
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/*'
        exclude 'plugin.xml'
        exclude 'plugin.properties'
        exclude 'about_files/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            jacoco {
                includeNoLocationClasses = true
            }
        }
    }
    jacoco {
        version = '0.7.3.201502191951'
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}
configurations {
    checkerFrameworkAnnotatedJDK {
        description = 'a copy of JDK classes with Checker Framework type qualifers inserted'
    }
}

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest', 'createDebugCoverageReport']) {

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*', '**/*Test*.*', 'android/**/*.*',
                      'com/handshake/hsdm/demo/**','com/handshake/hsdm/localstorage/schema1/*Dao*',
                      'com/handshake/hsdm/localstorage/schema1/*Factory*', 'com/handshake/hsdm/dagger2',
                      '**/*Module*', '**/*_Factory*', '**/*_MembersInjector*'
    ]
    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])
    executionData = fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", includes: [
            "jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec",
            "outputs/code-coverage/connected/*coverage.ec"
    ])

    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude: ['com/handshake/hsdm/demo/**'])
        })
    }
}
dependencies {
//Clipping dependencies 

    ext.checkerFrameworkVersion = '2.2.1'
    implementation "org.checkerframework:checker-qual:${checkerFrameworkVersion}"
    annotationProcessor "org.checkerframework:checker:${checkerFrameworkVersion}"
    checkerFrameworkAnnotatedJDK "org.checkerframework:jdk8:${checkerFrameworkVersion}"

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile).all { compile ->
        if (compile.name.contains("checkTypes")) {
            compile.options.compilerArgs += [
                    "-Xbootclasspath/p:${configurations.checkerFrameworkAnnotatedJDK.asPath}"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:  For future readers-  the line             javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.classNames +=["org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.NullnessChecker"] seems to be the problem.  removing it runs dagger and other annotation processors, but obviously won't run the checker.

Comment: Where and how are you getting the error?

Comment: When running gradlew checkTypes.  The exact message is "* What went wrong:
Task 'checkTypes' not found in root project 'HSDM'."

Comment: Their docs say "To run the checkers, build using the checkTypes variant". The line beneath that `gradlew checkTypes` is wrong, as that's not how you build a build type, any more than you do a `debug` build via `gradlew debug`. It's `gradlew assembleDebug`  or `gradlew installDebug`. However, I have never tried a mixed-case build type like `checkTypes, so I'm not sure how the task name gets assembled. Look in your Gradle tool in Android Studio and see what tasks are there, or list the tasks at the command line, and see what shows up.

Comment: There is an assembleCheckTypes.  Running it sets off a build, but doesn't do any annotation processing-  all of my AutoFactory classes are missing, which breaks the rest of Dagger.

Comment: That'll take a Checker-experienced hand to answer, I suspect. Leastways, I haven't a clue on that -- sorry!

Comment: One of the checker people had a guess that turned out right-  if you specify a AnnotationProcessor then it overwrites the default set and all AnnotationProcessors need to be specified.  So I had to manually add AutoFactory and Dagger.  Works great I'm going to be very happy having compile time nullness and ui effect checking.

Answer (score 2):

So apparently if you specify 1 annotation processor via classnames, it overwrites any others.  So I had to specify dagger and autofactory as well.  Then I can either run it from Android Studio as a build, or from command line as:

```
gradlew assembleCheckTypes
```